# QT QWidget на весь экран

Tags: qt

Унаследовал класс он QWidget,задал ему фон... показываю через showFullScreen(), но почему то виджет не растягивается на весь экран, а оставляет часть области не занятой...

**Вопрос:** как растянуть QWidget так, чтобы он занимал весь экран?

Comment: Скриншот бы...

Comment: http://minus.com/i/FRuL5cVppGL9  скрин на десктопе

Comment: и http://minus.com/i/kihlvvnJR8Zg  на Android

Comment: Версия qt 5.2.1

Comment: @Vadimcg А я ведь ждал, когда загрузится картинка. Не надо так!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Ответ на Ваш вопрос зависит от того как именно Вы произвели реализацию наследования от `QWidget`. Все дело в том, что если вы используете Layout (`QVBoxLayout`, `QHBoxLayout` или любой другой), то по умолчанию у Layout задан параметр `margin` (т.е. отступ) не нулевой, а некоторое число по умолчанию, возможно по этому вы видите не заполненные области по краям. Если так, то решить проблему просто: необходимо задать в Вашем Layout значение отступов равным 0, например так:

```
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Если же вы не используете Layout'ов, то значит проблема в другом и тогда желательно увидеть реализацию Вашего виджета в коде)

Успехов!